# Question about QThread implementation

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread

A QThread object represents a single thread of execution. But is the OS thread created when the QThread object is created, or when the `start()` method is called?

I'm interested in whether I can have several QThread objects lying around, and the OS will create threads on `start()` and kill them after `run()` returns, and then I can reuse the QThread objects again. But I don't want to hold OS resources while the QThread objects are not doing anything.

(for the record, I'm aware of QtConcurrent and the QThreadPool, and no, they don't satisfy my needs in this situation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Linux the thread object is created (via `pthread_create`) during the `QThread::start` method. It looks about the same with Windows.

You can see the source here:

Unix: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/master/src/corelib/thread/qthread_unix.cpp (line 542).

Windows: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/master/src/corelib/thread/qthread_win.cpp (line 419).